# checkout.fi payment gateway implement (convert php code to asp.net with C#)

Tags: asp.net, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, md5, payment-gateway

I am implementing checkout.fi payment gateway. I got the source code in php and java.I don't have any idea about php. That's why I want to convert Php source code to Asp.net code. Any Help Please
Below link given the sample code of PHP
https://checkoutfinland.github.io/#testing
and other sample java code link on github
https://github.com/AgiSol/checkout-java/

i have made code in asp.net but it is not working. For reference i have taking a Test Data. Below my code. This code run on button click event.

Code here

```
<pre><code>   
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){         
    string ver = "0001";
    string stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
    string amount = "1000";
    string refer = "2432324";
    string message = "hi";
    string language = "FI";
    string returnurl = "domain.com/return.aspx";
    string cancelurl = "domain.com/cancel.aspx";
    string reject = "2";
    string delaye = "";
    string country = "FIN";
    string currency = "EUR";
    string device = "10"; // 10 = XML
    string content = "1";
    string type = "0";
    string algorithms = "3";
    string delivery_date = "20171207";
    string firstname = "Tarun";
    string family = "Parmar";
    string address = "Ääkköstie 5b3\nKulmaravintolan yläkerta";
    string postcode = "33100";
    string postoffice = "Tampere";
    string MERCHANT="375917";
    string  SECRET_KEY= "SAIPPUAKAUPPIAS";
    string macnew =  encryptionMD5(ver,  stamp, amount, refer, message, language,MERCHANT ,returnurl, cancelurl, reject,delaye, country,currency, device, content, type,algorithms, delivery_date, firstname,family, address, postcode,postoffice, SECRET_KEY).ToUpper();

   string email = "support@checkout.fi";
   string phone = "0800552010";
   string status = "1";
   string generatedMac = GetHashSha256(ver,stamp, refer, amount, status, algorithms, SECRET_KEY);

    NameValueCollection collections = new NameValueCollection();
    collections.Add("VERSION", ver);
    collections.Add("STAMP", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"));
    collections.Add("AMOUNT",  amount);
    collections.Add("REFERENCE", refer);
    collections.Add("MESSAGE", message);
    collections.Add("LANGUAGE", language);
    collections.Add("RETURN", "domain.com/return.aspx");
    collections.Add("CANCEL", "domain.com/cancel.aspx");
    collections.Add("REJECT",  reject);
    collections.Add("DELAYED", delaye);
    collections.Add("COUNTRY",  country);
    collections.Add("CURRENCY", currency);
    collections.Add("DEVICE",  device);
    collections.Add("CONTENT", content);
    collections.Add("TYPE", type);
    collections.Add("ALGORITHM", algorithms);
    collections.Add("DELIVERY_DATE", delivery_date);
    collections.Add("FIRSTNAME", firstname);
    collections.Add("FAMILYNAME", family);
    collections.Add("ADDRESS",address);        
    collections.Add("POSTCODE",  postcode);
    collections.Add("POSTOFFIC", postoffice);
    collections.Add("MAC", macnew);
    collections.Add("EMAIL", email);        
    collections.Add("PHONE",  phone);
    collections.Add("MERCHANT",MERCHANT);
    collections.Add("SECRET_KEY", SECRET_KEY); 

    string remoteUrl = "https://payment.checkout.fi";      
    string html = "<html><head>";
    html += "</head><body onload='document.forms[0].submit()'>";
    html += string.Format("<form name='PostForm' method='POST' action='{0}'>", remoteUrl);
    foreach (string key in collections.Keys)
    {
        html += string.Format("<input name='{0}' type='text' value='{1}'>", key, collections[key]);
    }
    html += "</form></body></html>";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1";
    Response.Write(html);
    Response.End();
}
```

Function For encryptionMD5

```
 public string encryptionMD5(String VERSION, String STAMP, String AMOUNT, String REFERENCEs, String MESSAGE, String LANGUAGE, String merchantId, String RETURN, String CANCEL, String REJECT, String DELAYED, String COUNTRY, String CURRENCY, String DEVICE, String CONTENT, String TYPE, String ALGORITHM, String DELIVERY_DATE, String FIRSTNAME, String FAMILYNAME, String ADDRESS, String POSTCODE, String POSTOFFICE, String PasswordID)
    {

        string  passwords = VERSION + STAMP + AMOUNT + REFERENCEs + MESSAGE + LANGUAGE + merchantId + RETURN + CANCEL + REJECT + DELAYED + COUNTRY + CURRENCY + DEVICE + CONTENT + TYPE + ALGORITHM + DELIVERY_DATE + FIRSTNAME + FAMILYNAME + ADDRESS + POSTCODE + POSTOFFICE + PasswordID;
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] encrypt;
        UTF8Encoding encode = new UTF8Encoding(); 
        encrypt = md5.ComputeHash(encode.GetBytes(passwords));
```

```
       StringBuilder encryptdata = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i= 0; i<encrypt.Length; i++)   {
               encryptdata.Append(encrypt[i].ToString());
          }
         return encryptdata.ToString();
  }
```

Function For GetHashSha256

```
<pre><code>

public string GetHashSha256(string  VERSION,string STAMP, string REFERENCE,string PAYMENT, string STATUS, string ALGORITHM, string password)

    {
        string text = VERSION + STAMP + REFERENCE + PAYMENT + STATUS + ALGORITHM + password;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string hashString = string.Empty;
        foreach (byte x in hash)
        {
            hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }
        return hashString;
    }
```

This above code give below error

Creating a Payment Transaction failed (-24).
Error in field: MAC

Thanks in Advance if anybody help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Finland checkout payment gateway means that your MAC is not hashed correctly. I downloaded the java version from their github and it works perfectly. You are not generating the correct MD5 hash.

Quite a few problems in your code. First of all you must append + sign with each of the strings because they do same in Java. Second, you are assigning algorithms = "3". You should use algorithms = "2" for MD5. Third your encryptionMD5 doesn't returns correct hash.

Below is the correct implementation that I have done for you:

```
    string ver = "0001";
    string stamp = "kpjkq1510841290161";
    string amount = "1490";
    string refer = "12345";
    string message = "My custom message";
    string language = "FI";
    string returnurl = "http://localhost/success";
    string cancelurl = "http://localhost/cancel";
    string reject = "http://localhost/rejected";
    string delaye = "http://localhost/delayed";
    string country = "FIN";
    string currency = "EUR";
    string device = "10"; // 10 = XML
    string content = "1";
    string type = "0";
    string algorithms = "2";
    string delivery_date = "20171123";
    string firstname = "Tero";
    string family = "Testaaja";
    string address = "Mystreet 1";
    string postcode = "12345";
    string postoffice = "Tampere";
    string MERCHANT = "375917";
    string SECRET_KEY = "SAIPPUAKAUPPIAS";

using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
            {
                string fromValue = String.Join("+", new string[] { ver, stamp, amount, refer, message, language, MERCHANT, returnurl, cancelurl, reject, delaye, country, currency, device, content, type, algorithms, delivery_date, firstname, family, address, postcode, postoffice, SECRET_KEY });
                string macnew = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, fromValue);
            }

public string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
        {
            // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
            byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
            // and create a string.
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
            // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            // Return the hexadecimal string.
            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

> Output is c84e068fcab5c4dad93a29dd4c567b7f

Verified from finland checkout java github project.

And one tip is that you should use StringBuilder for appending text instead of concatenating with + sign for improved performance.

Comment: Thanks for reply and giving me suggestion.i have added this your function GetMd5Hash, algorithm value, other changes as per your suggestion  in my code. still i am getting error can you do this whole code how to send payment request and how to get response?

Comment: I am getting same error. "Maksutapahtuman luonti ei onnistunut (-24).

Error in field/Virhekentässä: MAC"

Comment: i got the same output of mac like your output using above  value but after sending data not happening anything. so will you help i will also ready to pay some amount.

Comment: it is strange. java app generates same mac if i provide above values. please put your code on github so i can check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. here i am giving the gdrive shared link or give me your email id so i will also send on your email id. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N2pn_cMV4VAvxjqLKI7gxFsPG29wgUZG